# How to get the stats for an individual website in addition to combined stats?

Tags: google-analytics

I have two websites:

http://unit.example.edu

and

http://m.unit.example.edu

The second website is a smartphone version (simplified, just a few pages of basic information) of the first website.

I have add the following code on both websites:

```
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-12345-6");
pageTracker._setDomainName('unit.example.edu');
pageTracker._trackPageview();
```

I am able to see the combined stats for both websites, which is what I want.

Now I want to be able to see the stats such as pageviews for each individual website. How can I do this conveniently within google analytics?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set "hostname" as secondary dimension in you standard reports (you can also add the hostname to the site url via a view filter, but that won't work for data that is already collected).

"Secondary domain" is a dropdown in standard reports with data tables (a dropdown in the table header). The problem with that is that the setting is lost when you navigate from the page (you can create a shortcut which will keep the setting). Secondary dimension cannot be set on overview pages (only with data tables).

Alternatively you can create a custom segment. Expand segments (downwards arrow in the upper left), click "new segment", goto "conditions", select "hostname", enter the name of a domain as value, assign a name to the segment and click "save".  Now you can look at the data for the distinct domain you selected in your conditions. You can create (for any practical purpose) as many segments as you want and compare up to four segments side by side in most standard reports.

Comment: could you please tell me how to get the secondary dimension? Suppose I start with Behavior->Overview page? I am unable to find it.

Comment: I added some clarifications and an alternative approach to the answer.